# static void c# webmethod can't reference user control?

Tags: c#, ajax, webmethod

I have a WebMethod where I just want to flip a property to true.

I am putting it in the code-behind of a .aspx page using C#.

```
public partial class Data : Base
{ 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.bgc1.BGEnabled = false;
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void EnableBellows()
    {
        this.bgc1.BGEnabled = true;            
    }
}
```

I declare the property in the .ascx.cs file:

```
private bool _enabled = true;

public bool BGEnabled
{
    get { return _enabled; }
    set { _enabled = value; }
}
```

Lastly I call the WebMethod with a jQuery Ajax post.

I am getting the error that `this` is not valid in a static property. This error is only in the WebMethod but not in the Page_Load.

My goal is to flip BGEnabled to true. If my approach is incorrect, what will I need to do differently? I need to be able to do it from an ajax post.

Comment: inside static method you can't access to object, see more on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am getting the error that this is not valid in a static property.

Indeed. In fact, in this case, it's a static method.

A static member is one which is associated with the type, rather than with any *instance* of the type - so here, we could call `EnableBellows` directly as:

```
Data.EnableBellows();
```

... without creating any instance of `Data`. As `this` is meant to refer to "the instance of the object that the method was called on", it's meaningless in a static member.

You need to think about where your data would come from, and what you'd do with the modified data. Bear in mind that the web method is *not* called as part of loading the page, so it doesn't have access to any of the controls on the page, etc.

Basically, I suspect you need to revisit the whole notion of web methods and ASP.NET pages.

Comment: Thanks. I am running a bit out of idea as I would like to avoid a .net postback was well.

Comment: Well we can't really tell what you're attempting to achieve here, but you'll probably need to provide the web method with *some* context, if it's going to persist a change, for example. The first thing to do is make sure you understand the problem - if you're very new to C#, I'd actually recommend putting ASP.NET down for the moment and learning the basics of the language via console apps.

Answer (score 1):

Inside static method you can only access static methods/objects or instancesdeclared inside the scope of the static method